# Python recursive powerset function for tuples

Tags: python, list, recursion, tuples

I am trying to create a function that returns a powerset (all subsets of a given tuple of numbers) in the form of a tuple of tuples.

I have followed code that I have found previously, but this returns the output as a list of lists rather than a tuple of tuples.

```
def subs(S):
    if S == []:
        return [[]]

    x = subs(S[1:])

    return x + [[S[0]] + y for y in x]
```

This correctly returns: `[[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]` for an input of `subs([1,2,3])`

However I am looking for the function to input a tuple and return a tuple of tuples, such that the output would be:

```
>>> print (subs((1,2,3))
((), (3), (2), (2, 3), (1), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3))
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function for lists can be converted to use tuples instead.  There is no direct equivalent of a list comprehension because the object needs to be mutable during the loop, but the result can be converted using `tuple()`.  Care is needed with the syntax for 1-element tuples, so some extra commas have to be inserted in a couple of places.

```
def subs(S):
    if S == ():
        return ((),)

    x = subs(S[1:])

    return x + tuple([(S[0],) + y for y in x])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying something very similar but didn't account for the commas. Makes much more sense now

Comment: @dontknowwhatimdoing Yes, the difficulty with one-element tuples is that `(a)` is simply an expression that evaluates to `a` with the normal use of parentheses, so it is necessary to insert an additional comma in the code, i.e. `(a,)`. However, this is a syntax issue only, and once created, they behave in the normal way as for any other tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

`pip install more-itertools`

```py
from more_itertools import powerset
print(tuple([x for x in powerset( (1, 2, 3) )]))
```

Output:

```
((), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but I am not allowed to use external tools or functions, I must write the function myself. Any ideas in that case?

Comment: I don't want to work on this problem since this seems like a homework to me. That said, I'll leave you with a hint. Tuples and lists are pretty close.  You can perform slicing on both of them. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

mashing tuples together or making new tuples from old ones is a bit tricky because they are immutable.  Here is a hint that may put you in the right direction, along with the tip about indexing in the other solution.  You can use the "scatter" operator to unpack an existing tuple into pieces when making a new one as such:

```
In [12]: c = ((2,3),(4,),(99,0,8))                                              

In [13]: d = (*c, (7,6,5))                                                      

In [14]: d                                                                      
Out[14]: ((2, 3), (4,), (99, 0, 8), (7, 6, 5))
```